# What is the correct way to listen to both UDS and TCP sockets in a `fork()` based server?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, posix, unix-socket

I'm writing a `fork()` based server, the TCP sockets are the communication channel of the clients with the server and the UDS socket (datagram, if it makes any difference) is the communication channel of a *management console* with the server.

What would be the correct way to listen to both socket types? My server currently looks pretty much as the `fork()` server in Beej's example:

```
while(1) {  // main accept() loop
    sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
    new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
    if (new_fd == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        continue;
    }

    inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
        get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
        s, sizeof s);
    printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

    if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
        close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
        if (send(new_fd, "Hello, world!", 13, 0) == -1)
            perror("send");
        close(new_fd);
        exit(0);
    }
    close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
}
```

How would you add to the above code the ability to listen and wait for connection in a UDS socket (that was already binded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `select()`, `poll()`, or `epoll()` (`epoll()` does assume Linux.)

Or use multiple threads.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple threads? I don't want to use I/O multiplexing for a reason (an educational one)

Comment: Use the original thread to listen to one port and start another to listen to the other.